# Ansible find replace is not working for 2 lines

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Cassandra cassandra.yaml
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ home}}/conf/cassandra.yaml"
    state: present
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
#   backup: yes
 with_items:
 - { regexp: "data_file_directories:", line: "data_file_directories: \n               - {{ data_directory }}" }
```

in the first file first run it looks good but in the second run it keeps adding new line. what needs to be done in order to the second run also looks good.

```
 data_file_directories:
               - /mount1/data
```

second run

```
 data_file_directories:
               - /mount1/data
               - /mount1/data
               - /mount1/data
```

I want some thing like

```
data_file_directories:
               - /mount1/data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineinfile` ― as its name suggest ― is a module to ensure a certain **line** is in the target file; not **lines**.

---

To deal with multiple lines either:

- use [`regexp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html) with matchgroup and backreference ― the exact implementation is dependent on other constructs in the target file,
- use [`blockinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/blockinfile_module.html) ― the exact implementation is dependent on other constructs in the target file,
- or (**preferably**) use [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html).